# Is there any way to encrypt PYTHON output file like exe in C?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I am writing some personal information like account password in .py file. Is there any way so that no can read the content of file but can run it like exe in C++ or C#. In short reverse engineering should not be possible.

Comment: The equivalent program written in C would be just as reverse engineerable. Heck, running [`strings`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?strings) would probably do it.

Comment: u might wanna look in `pyCrypto`

Comment: If you got some sort of string that is unique to your computer, and used it to encrypt/decrypt the password, that would make it so at least it could only be decrypted on your computer... not exactly secure, but a little bit better.